tsup not including the css file path
Im creating my typeScript build using tsup, its reading the style.css file and making its build in the dist/index.css as well, but its not including its filename path in the file. I keep importing my filepath manually by doing import './index.css'  in the build folder.
      //main.tsx 
        import '../assets/style.css';
        const func = () => {
        return (
        //do something
        );
        };

        export { func };

        //index.ts
        export * from "./src/types";
        export * from "./src/main";

        //tsup config
        import { defineConfig } from 'tsup';
        
        export default defineConfig({
            format: ['cjs', 'esm'],
            entry: ['./index.ts'],
            dts: true,
            shims: true,
            skipNodeModulesBundle: true,
            clean: true,
        });

        //typescript config
        {
            "compilerOptions": {
                "strict": true,
                "noImplicitAny": true,
                "esModuleInterop": true,
                "strictNullChecks": true,
                "target": "ES2022",
                "moduleResolution": "Node10",
                "module": "CommonJS",
                "declaration": true,
                "isolatedModules": true,
                "noEmit": true,
                "outDir": "dist",
                "jsx": "react" 
            },
            "include": ["src", "custom.d.ts", "index.ts"],
            "exclude": ["node_modules"]
        }



        //package.json

        {
          "name": "someFile",
          "version": "1.0.12",
          "description": "toast description",
          "main": "./dist/index.js",
          "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
          "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
          "scripts": {
            "build": "tsup --watch"
          },
          "keywords": [
            "toast"
          ],
          "author": "burhan",
          "license": "ISC",
          "peerDependencies": {
            "react": "^18.2.0",
            "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "react": "^18.2.0",
            "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
            "zustand": "^4.5.2"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
            "@types/react": "^18.3.0",
            "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
            "react": "^18.2.0",
            "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
            "tsup": "^8.0.2",
            "typescript": "^5.4.5"
          }
        }


I've tried including postcss and tailwind as well but its not including the css path in the build index.js

I'm facing the same issue. AHve you ever found a solution?

Same here. Any solution?
